# CSS chained sibling selectors?

Tags: html, css

Given the html:

```
  <div class="apples">
    <div class="apple"></div>
    <div class="apple"></div><br>
  </div>
  <div class="oranges">
    <div class="apple"></div>
    <div class="apple"></div>
  </div>
```

.. I'd like to have the margin between two `.apple`s in the `.apples` div to be `15px` but for there to be no margin between the apples in the oranges div.

I could do:

```
.apple + .apple{
    margin-left:15px;
}
```

..but that add the margin to the `.apple`s in `.oranges` as well.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
.apples > .apple + .apples > .apple{
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

..but, not surprisingly, that didn't work.

to fiddle with: http://jsbin.com/ijagoc/1/edit

Comment: ah, I see from the next answer you've updated your fiddle since posting the link

Comment: @o.v. yup, oops. I forget to create a milestone with JSbin. Thanks for showing up!

Answer (score 2):

```
.apples > .apple + .apple {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

or you could do a first child selector to also support more than one inner div:

```
.apples .apple {
    margin-left: 15px;
.apples .apple:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, figured this out just a second ago. The spec made it clear: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors